# How to contextualize Symfony 2 routes without request parameters

Tags: symfony, routes, doctrine-orm

I've been searching high and low for a solution here, but I'm not really finding what I need. It may just be that I'm not searching for the right thing.

For the admin backend of my app, I currently grab a user for a controller like this:

```
//routing.yml
view_user:
    pattern: /user/{id}/
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:User:view }

//UserController.php
use Sauce\AppBundle\Entity\User;

public function viewAction(User $user)
{
    $user->getSauce();
}
```

For the frontend where a user doesn't fetch themselves at each URL using an id, this doesn't work. Is it possible to do this without having an id in the URL? My first thought of how to make a user easily available is something like:

```
/**
 * A fast way to grab the user throughout this class.
 */
public function getUser() {
    return $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
}

public function viewAction()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    ...
}
```

But this, to me, seems way below Symfony 2 standards. I must be overlooking something more elegant. Any insights out there?

Answer (score 0):

Yea, creating a helper method is the way to go. You could move it to a base controller to stay DRY. My [abstract base controller](https://github.com/elnur/ElnurAbstractControllerBundle/blob/master/AbstractController.php) provides such a method.

There is no “magic” way of doing this I'm aware of.